# PHP cookie set within Drupal inaccessible in non-Drupal script

Tags: php, cookies, drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

I'm setting a cookie within a Drupal app that's hosted on Pantheon (let's just say the URL is domain.com/step/1) immediately before redirecting to an external URL like this:

```
$expires = time()+(60*60*24);
setrawcookie('tourPath', '/step/1', $expires, '/');
header('Location: http://www.someexternalurl.com?redirect='.$callback_url);
```

The external URL handles the request in a way that isn't really relevant to this question, but it then redirects to `$callback_url`. Let's say it's `domain.com/callback`. Regardless, it's on the same domain, but it's just a plain PHP script (not within Drupal).

The problem I'm having here is that when the redirect to the callback script happens, **I can see in my browser that the `tourPath` cookie is set, but it's not in the $_COOKIE array.**

I can see various Drupal cookies in $_COOKIE, so there isn't some problem with setting cookies in general.

I tried using `setcookie()` instead, but that didn't help.

Comment: As a side-note, setting this `tourPath` variable within the callback URL isn't possible due to limitations out of my control on the external service: They require that all redirect URLs get whitelisted, so it would be a huge pain to have to whitelist every single /step/1, /step/2, /step/3, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with pantheon and setting your own cookies/session vars you'll need to prepend the cookie name with "SESS" according to their docs here:

https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/varnish/caching-advancedtopics/

So instead of:

```
setcookie('hi', 'howareyou?');
```

You'll need to use:

```
setcookie('SESShi', 'howareyou?');
```